# Sorting data MySql

Tags: mysql

I have got a table like this:

```
id     content  parent_id
265    flower   NULL    
266    shroom   NULL    
267    ccccccc  NULL    
268    ddddddd  NULL    
275    b1       266 
276    b2       266 
277    sub text 275
```

and I want this output:

```
id     content  parent_id
265    flower   NULL    
266    shroom   NULL
275    b1       266 
277    sub text 275 
276    b2       266     
267    ccccccc  NULL    
268    ddddddd  NULL
```

In words: Sort it by null and if it has got parent_id I want to put it under it in DESC order.

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM notes
ORDER BY if (parent_id is not null, parent_id, id) id
```

sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0418a7/1/0

Comment: Your expected output seems to be ordered by content rather than parent_id.

Comment: Order by content ...  or order by parent_id asc

Comment: i don't want to order it by content.

Comment: `I want to put [descendants under ancestors] in DESC order` - you might, but I see _ascending_ order (275 before 276 for parent 266). (Do you mean _recursively_: all descendants of a child before any further children?)

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested this.  Try something along these lines, though.

```
select id, content, parent_id
  from notes
order by coalesce(parent_id, id);
```

This will still create a situation where the child comes before the parent (rarely but possible).